# Error while running Java service wrapper for JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jboss7.x, java-service-wrapper

I'm trying to make Jboss Application Server 7.1.0 run as a service using the Java service wrapper, I already solved many problems but for each one I solve I get a new one. Currently I'm using this configuration:

```
# Java Application
#wrapper.java.command=java
wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe


# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%OG_HOME%/bin/wrapper-3.2.3.jar 
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%JBOSS_HOME%/modules/org/jboss/as/server/main/jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=%JBOSS_HOME%/modules/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=%JBOSS_HOME%/modules/org/jboss/stdio/main/jboss-stdio-1.0.1.GA.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.5=%JBOSS_HOME%/modules/org/jboss/as/controller/main/jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.6=%JBOSS_HOME%/modules/org/jboss/logmanager/log4j/main/jboss-logmanager-log4j-1.0.0.GA.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.7=%JBOSS_HOME%/modules/org/apache/log4j/main/log4j-1.2.16.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.8=%JBOSS_HOME%/jboss-modules.jar


#wrapper.java.classpath.2=%JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar
#wrapper.java.classpath.3=%JBOSS_HOME%/bin/run.jar

# used to avoid problems with quotes inside the PATH environment variable
wrapper.java.library.path.append_system_path=TRUE

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=%OG_HOME%bin
wrapper.java.library.path.2=%JBOSS_HOME%\lib

# these are the JAVA_OPTS
wrapper.java.additional.1=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=false
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dlogging.configuration=file:%JBOSS_HOME%/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl
wrapper.java.additional.9-Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full-ACE2.xml

#wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=64

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=512

# Location of OG log folder
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.jboss.modules.Main
wrapper.app.parameter.2=%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.3=-mp
wrapper.app.parameter.4=%JBOSS_HOME%\modules
wrapper.app.parameter.5=-jaxpmodule 
wrapper.app.parameter.6=javax.xml.jaxp-provider
wrapper.app.parameter.7=org.jboss.as.standalone
wrapper.app.parameter.8=-Djboss.home.dir=%JBOSS_HOME%
# Data source definitions are needed for the wait for DB Service


#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=DEBUG

# wrapper log location
wrapper.logfile=%OG_HOME%/log/ace2_wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=DEBUG

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10mb

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Properties
#********************************************************************
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=ACE2 on JBOSS Service Wrapper console

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name=JbossServiceForACE2

# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=Oblicore - ACE2 on JBOSS Application Server

# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description=JEE Application Server Running ACE2 Manager

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
```

But when running it I get this error:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:31 | --> Wrapper Started as Console
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:31 | Using tick timer.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | server listening on port 32000.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Launching a JVM...
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\java.exe" -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=false -Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\CA\Cloud Insight\bin;C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\lib;C:\Program Files\CA\SC\CAWIN\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;C:\oracle\product\11.1.0\db_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\ScanEngine;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\CAUpdate\;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\ThirdParty\;C:\Program Files\CA\SharedComponents\SubscriptionLicense\;C:\Program Files\CA\eTrustITM;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\CA\DSM\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\CA\SC\CAM\bin;C:\Program Files\CA\Cloud Insight\bin" -classpath "C:\Program Files\CA\Cloud Insight\/bin/wrapper-3.2.3.jar;C:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules/org/jboss/as/server/main/jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar;C:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar;C:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules/org/jboss/stdio/main/jboss-stdio-1.0.1.GA.jar;C:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules/org/jboss/as/controller/main/jboss-as-controller-7.1.0.Final.jar;C:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules/org/jboss/logmanager/log4j/main/jboss-logmanager-log4j-1.0.0.GA.jar;C:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules/org/apache/log4j/main/log4j-1.2.16.jar;C:/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/jboss-modules.jar" -Dwrapper.key="0wwz4AsNMPAgFGNc" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=3324 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.jboss.modules.Main C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\jboss-modules.jar -mp C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | JVM started (PID=5612)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main  Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@47858e
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Running a 32-bit JVM.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Loading native library failed: wrapper-windows-x86-32.dll  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-windows-x86-32 in java.library.path
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Loaded native library: wrapper.dll
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Calling native initialization method.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Initializing WrapperManager native library.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Java Executable: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\java.exe
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Windows version: 6.0.6002
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Java Version   : 1.6.0_17-b04 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Java VM Vendor : Sun Microsystems Inc.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Control event monitor thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Startup runner thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@5e3974, args["C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\jboss-modules.jar", "-mp", "C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\modules", "-jaxpmodule", "javax.xml.jaxp-provider", "org.jboss.as.standalone", "-Djboss.home.dir=C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final"]) called by thread: main
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Communications runner thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Opened Socket from 31000 to 32000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Send a packet KEY : 0wwz4AsNMPAgFGNc
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | handleSocket(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=32000,localport=31000])
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31000
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | read a packet KEY : 0wwz4AsNMPAgFGNc
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Got key from JVM: 0wwz4AsNMPAgFGNc
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | send a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 30
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Start Application.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | send a packet START : start
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Wrapper Manager: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Received a packet PING_TIMEOUT : 30
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | PingTimeout from Wrapper is 30000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Received a packet START : start
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | calling WrapperListener.start()
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Waiting for WrapperListener.start runner thread to complete.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | WrapperSimpleApp: invoking main method
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Slot has invalid characters or is empty
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Slot has invalid characters or is empty
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 |   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleIdentifier.fromString(ModuleIdentifier.java:180)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 |   at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:253)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | WrapperSimpleApp: start(args) end.  Main Completed=true, exitCode=1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | returned from WrapperListener.start()
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | WrapperListener.start() returned an exit code of 1.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | WrapperManager.stop(1) called by thread: Wrapper-Connection
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Send a packet STOP : 1
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | read a packet STOP : 1
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | JVM requested a shutdown. (1)
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | wrapperStopProcess(1) called.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | Sending stop signal to JVM
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:32 | send a packet STOP : NULL
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:33 | Thread, Wrapper-Connection, handling the shutdown process.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:33 | shutdownJVM(1) Thread:Wrapper-Connection
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:33 | Send a packet STOPPED : 1
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:33 | read a packet STOPPED : 1
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:33 | JVM signalled that it was stopped.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:33 | Closing socket.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:33 | socket read no code (closed?).
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/12 14:26:33 | server listening on port 32002.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/12 14:26:34 | calling System.exit(1)
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:34 | JVM process exited with a code of 1, however the wrapper exit code was already 1.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:34 | JVM exited normally.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/03/12 14:26:34 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Couldn't find anything on the web :(

UPDATE: Thanks to the answers below i was able to solve that problem, but now I'm getting a new error, which , I think, is related to the OCI-JDBC driver:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 | 11:07:53,933 WARN  

[org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:758) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.7.Final.jar:1.0.7.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.fillToMin(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:703) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.7.Final.jar:1.0.7.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.7.Final.jar:1.0.7.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 | Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.getLibraryVersionNumber()I
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.getLibraryVersionNumber(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection$1.run(T2CConnection.java:3552)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.loadNativeLibrary(T2CConnection.java:3547)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:266)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:162)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:53)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:249)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |   ... 5 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/13 11:07:54 |
```

I saw some threads on the web saying that maybe the driver version is not up to date, but I'm not sure if they are referring to the DLL or jar?

**[UPDATE]:**

I've added the Oracle driver path using "wrapper.java.library.path" and it solved this error, but of course I now get a new one:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 | 10:51:38,468 WARN  

[org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:758) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.7.Final.jar:1.0.7.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.fillToMin(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:703) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.7.Final.jar:1.0.7.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.7.Final.jar:1.0.7.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_17]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 | Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Fetch error message failed!
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:751)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:414)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:162)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:53)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:249)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |   ... 5 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:38 |
```

Also, at the end of the log i see this:

```
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/14 10:51:42 | send a packet PING : ping
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:42 | Received a packet PING : ping
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:42 | Send a packet PING : ok
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/14 10:51:42 | read a packet PING : ok
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/14 10:51:42 | Got ping response from JVM
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/14 10:51:47 | send a packet PING : ping
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:47 | Received a packet PING : ping
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:47 | Send a packet PING : ok
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/14 10:51:47 | read a packet PING : ok
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/14 10:51:47 | Got ping response from JVM
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/14 10:51:51 | send a packet PING : ping
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:51 | Received a packet PING : ping
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/03/14 10:51:51 | Send a packet PING : ok
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/03/14 10:51:51 | read a packet PING : ok
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/03/14 10:51:51 | Got ping response from JVM
```

And It keeps going on like this until i stop the batch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure which post to answer on since it's been asked 3 times, but I'll do it on this one :-)

First of all that class path doesn't look right. None of those log4j libraries should be in your class path. In fact in future releases those are going away and will be pointed to different libraries in jboss-modules. The server class path should be figured out by jboss-modules.

Also this bit `-Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=org.jboss.logging.logmanager.LoggerPluginImpl` isn't needed and could cause a problem.

Where did you come up with this configuration BTW?

Answer (score 2):

[ coming from here: [Problems using java service wrapper with jboss 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654670/problems-using-java-service-wrapper-with-jboss-7) ]

Please take a look at wrapper.app.parameter.2:

> wrapper.app.parameter.2=%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar

I think this messes up the parameter parsing, leading to an IllegalArgumentException. 
Therefore, please remove this line and try again.

Furthermore, as James R. Perkins already pointed out, org.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass shouldn't be set. Your class path is also probably not necessary or even a bad idea to set log4j libraries into the classpath (with Jboss).

Lastly, the following property also needs attention:

> wrapper.java.additional.9-Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full-ACE2.xml

please note the missing equal sign.

cheers,

edit after the question was edited:

this is an exception caused because a native library wasn't found. Presumably your ocijdbc dll. 
Where is the file located?
you can configure the locations, the JVM will look for native(jni) libraries using the [wrapper.java.library.path property](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-java-library-path-n.html) .

Currently, the following locations are specified:

> wrapper.java.library.path.1=%OG_HOME%bin
>   wrapper.java.library.path.2=%JBOSS_HOME%\lib

path.1 looks a bit suspicious, since there is no file separator('\'), like it is on path.2 or any place OG_HOME was used in the conf file...

hopes this helps you out.

hi, the Wrapper is pinging the JVM by default every 5sec, which is a completely normal operation. This will also only show up in your log file in debug mode. Once you switch to another loglevel, it shouldn't appear in the log file. what are you meaning by service is not installed? Once your JBoss AS runs fine in console, you can install it as service using either the Install-App.bat file or running:

```
.\wrapper.exe -i ..\conf\wrapper.conf
```

hope this helps you out.

cheers,

Comment: Thank you both very much, unfortunately i can't mark 2 answers as correct so the first one gets the credit :). I've updated the question with a new error I get.

Comment: Again, thank you for your time, %OG_HOME% is a local environment variable we use in our app which contains all kind of drivers and stuff it was accidentally defined with a '\' and that is why i didn't put one in the definition (I will change it later).

I've added the Oracle driver path as you suggested and it seems to work but of course now i get a new error (I've edited the question).

Comment: hi, I'm not really sure about the internal error, happening in your jdbc driver. but assume that your jdbc driver version is incompatible with your oracle database version.... could you try another jdbc driver maybe?

Comment: I've tried replacing the driver but still with no luck, any clue regarding the ping messages at the end?

Comment: Update: I found a more updated driver and the error is gone :)

but I still have the ping problem and the service is not installed :(

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, i finally got it to work :)
You probably should write a tutorial for this...

Comment: Hi, glad you got up and running. We have tutorials for jboss AS 5 and 6 on our website, but not yet for 7. I will try to add that as well in the next days. cheers,